# Combine 3rd party enum with function

Tags: java, function, enums

I have 3rd party enum declaration:

```
enum Code {
  COUNTRY, STATE, CITY, ... 
}
```

My object:

```
public class A {
  String country;
  String state;
  String city;
  ...
}
```

I need to associate this enum with my object state changes. Something like:

```
public Set<Code> getChangedValuesCodes(A oldA, A newA) {
  Set<Code> codes = new HashSet<>();
  getCountryCode(oldA, newA).ifPresent(codes::add);
  getStateCode(oldA, newA).ifPresent(codes::add);
  getCityCode(oldA, newA).ifPresent(codes::add);
  return codes;
}

private Optional<Code> getCountryCode(A oldA, A newA) {
  return getCode(oldA.getCountry(), newA.getCountry(), Code.COUNTRY);
}

private Optional<Code> getStateCode(A oldA, A newA) {
  return getCode(oldA.getState(), newA.getState(), Code.STATE);
}

private Optional<Code> getCityCode(A oldA, A newA) {
  return getCode(oldA.getCity(), newA.getCity(), Code.CITY);
}

private Optional<Code> getCode(Object oldObj, Object newObj, Code code) {
  return !oldObj.equals(newObj) && newObj != null
    ? of(code)
    : empty();
}
```

Problem is that there are a lot of codes and `A` object is pretty big.
Having a class looks a little messy too me.

I am thinking about association through the enum.

```
public enum ACode {
  COUNTRY(Code.COUNTRY) {
    @Override
    boolean isChanged(A oldA, A newA) {
      return ACode.isPropertyChanged(oldA.getCountry(), newA.getCountry());
    }
  },
  CITY(Code.CITY) {
    @Override
    boolean isChanged(A oldA, A newA) {
      return ACode.isPropertyChanged(oldA.getCity(), newA.getCity());
    }
  },
  STATE(Code.STATE) {
    @Override
    boolean isChanged(A oldA, A newA) {
      return ACode.isPropertyChanged(oldA.getState(), newA.getState());
    }
  };

  @Getter
  private final Code code;

  ACode(Code code) {
    this.code = code;
  }

  public static Set<Code> getChangedValuesCodes(A oldA, A newA) {
    return Arrays.stream(ACode.values())
        .filter(code -> code.isChanged(oldA, newA))
        .map(ACode::getCode)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
  }

  abstract boolean isChanged(A oldA, A newA);

  private static boolean isPropertyChanged(Object oldObject, Object newObject) {
    return !oldObject.equals(newObject) && newObject != null;
  }
}
```

This one looks better than upper one but still clumsy as I am not technically using this enum - more like a connector of enum and the function.

How could I achieve a clean association between this enum and the function in order to get all changed values codes?